# Do define() statements need phpDocumentor-style docblocks?

Tags: documentation, coding-standards

There's no word on this in the [WordPress Documentation Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/inline-documentation-standards/php-documentation-standards/), but do `define()` statements need phpDocumentor-style docblocks?

```
/**
 * Should this docblock be here?
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
define( 'MY_CONST', 'Hello' );


// Or would a comment be more appropriate?
define( 'MY_CONST', 'Hello' );
```

For reference, the list of elements to be dockblock'd that are mentioned in the standards document are:

- Functions and class methods
- Classes
- Class properties
- Requires and includes
- Hooks (actions and filters)
- Inline comments
- File headers
- Constants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the section [Constants](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/inline-documentation-standards/php-documentation-standards/#7-constants) in the [Wordpress: PHP Documentation Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/inline-documentation-standards/php-documentation-standards/) is pretty clear. It should look like this:

```
/**
 * Summary.
 *
 * @since x.x.x (if available)
 * @var type $var Description.
 */
define( 'MY_CONST', 'Hello' );
```